# How to override method Class<?>.getAt in Groovy

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

Currently I'm using Groovy 1.8.2 and the following code works for me as expected:

```
Class.metaClass.getAt = { args ->
    println "Called ${delegate}[${args}]"
    TypeDefinition.create(delegate, args)
}
```

I use that in my DSL as shown:

```
TypeDefinition instance = List[MyOwnClass]
```

When I moved to Groovy 2.0.5 this functinality failed with "Missing method: static java.util.List.getAt() with parameter some.package.MyOwnClass". So the question is how can I make it work with Groovy 2?

Comment: That works for me with Groovy 2.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a category works with 2.0.5:

```
class ClassHelperCategory {
    static getAt(Class cls, String arg) {
        "Called $cls[$arg]"
    }
}

Class.metaClass.mixin(ClassHelperCategory)

assert List['hello'] == 'Called interface java.util.List[hello]'
```